# why casting to (LayoutManager) needed to setLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I'm learning the different ways to position objects in GUI and I don't really understand why its necessary  to cast  to `LayoutManager`  in order to use the `setLayout` method.
would it be necessary to implement the `LayoutManager` interface for this to work correctly ?

```
public class FlowL extends JApplet{

   public void init(){

         // why is the cast necessary ?  
        // an error occurs when  its   setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
        setLayout((LayoutManager) new FlowLayout());


 }

}
```

Comment: Do you have another class you defined as `FlowLayout` (as practice or something) in the same package?

Comment: no, isn't FlowLayout allready defined ? all i do is start adding  objects ? eg: 
    `setLayout(new FlowLayout());`
   `add(new Button("myButton"));`

Comment: _"defined"_, meaning _"named"_.  I see you named _this_ class `FlowL`, so that's why I asked. Maybe you created another class called `FlowLayout`. If you did, that's your problem. Otherwise I can't think of another reason.

Comment: and even though the error disapears  i get an error..

`java.lang.ClassCastException: flowLayout.FlowLayout cannot be cast to java.awt.LayoutManager`

Comment: mm ok,  no just  this class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "and even though the error disapears i get an error.. `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `flowLayout.FlowLayout` cannot be cast to `java.awt.LayoutManager`"

There *is* no standard Java class `flowLayout.FlowLayout`. That's *your* class (or possibly some third party class that doesn't extends LayoutManager, which I highly doubt).

You need to import

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
```

And get rid of your

```
import flowLayout.FlowLayout; // if you have that.
```

---

- Lesson to be learned: **Don't** name your classes the same as existing Java classes.